# Replace Non Stardard Characters '♯' in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

It just ignores this

```
var chordName = chord.name;
if (chordName != previousChordName) {
  chordName = chordName.replace('♯', '#');
  chordName = chordName.replace('♭', 'b');
  textBuffer.push(chordName); 
  previousChordName = chordName;
}
```

if put in text

```
var chordName = 'F♯m'.replace('♯', '#');
```

the result will be correct F#m
It will replace F with G no problem.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Are you certain `♯` isn't actually something like `&#x266F;` in the actual `chord.name` you're trying to process, and thus not being matched?

Comment: I'm not sure `replace` is safe for multi-byte characters, and I bet the sharp and flat characters are not single-byte.

Comment: @Tom It works when you do `'F♯m'.replace('♯', '#')` in the dev console, it properly returns "F#m"

Comment: @LuaStart maybe your issue is that you're never reassigning `chord.name` to have the new value of `chordName`? I don't see the need for the extra variable.

Comment: that is 'F♯m'? I don't see anything declared with that variable. Can anyone explain.

Comment: @seriously A "chord" is something in music theory. `"F♯m"` is possible chord, named "F-sharp minor". OP wants to be able to convert `F♯m` to `F#m` (sharp symbol to octothorpe aka hashtag), as well as `♭` to `b` (flat symbol to the letter b). So `"F♯m"` is a possible value of input as the variable `chordName` and `chord.name`

Comment: is ```♯``` and ```♭``` considered a valid character in javascript. if so this seems easy to fix. @Samathingamajig

Comment: Here's the code.js https://www.kvraudio.com/forum/download/file.php?id=38515

Comment: Also remember that .replace() will only replace the first occurance. Use .replaceAll() to replace all occurances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked

```
var chordName = chord.name;
if (chordName != previousChordName) {
  chordName1 = chordName.replace(/\u266f/, '#'); 
  chordName1 = chordName1.replace(/\u266d/, 'b');
  textBuffer.push(chordName1); 
  previousChordName = chordName;
}
```

Comment: Of course it did - it's the case of "not updating `chordName` at all" Using the regular expressions for replacement is, however, unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that and it didn't replace, the u266f u266d worked, same in the message trace it put F?m. replaceAll() was the first thing I tried on the end result but the Audio application's javascript didn't recognize it along with others. The previousChordName just puts a / in rather than the same chord name again |D / / /|/ / / /|/ / / /|A / / /| so it was doing |D D D D|

Answer (score 0):

The code will not work as expected because `previousChordName` is being set to the updated chord notation. Comparing a new chord that uses '♯' and'♭' marks with `previousChordName` will fail because the latter contains '#' and 'b' marks.

Either saving the input chord name before modifying it, or not updating `chordName` at all should fix the problem: E.G., using both ideas:

```
var chordName = chord.name;
if (chordName != previousChordName) {
  previousChordName = chordName;
  textBuffer.push(
    chordName.replace('♯', '#').replace('♭', 'b')
  ); 
}
```

To support [slash and/or polychord](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/104163/what-does-the-chord-notation-x-y-slash-chord-mean) chords, replace all sharps and flats in a chord rather than just the first. You couldt use `replaceAll` instead of `replace`, or provide a regular expression with a `/g` flag as the pattern to match. I.E.

```
string.replaceAll('♯', '#').replaceAll('♭', 'b'); // and 
string.replace(/♯/g, '#").replace(/♭/g, 'b')'
```

are equivalent.